# Send data to SOAP API involving repeated elements of same name

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have this XML structure:

```xml
<create_resource_inventory xmlns="urn:toa:activity">
    <user>
        <now></now>
        <login></login>
        <company></company>
        <auth_string></auth_string>
    </user>
    <resource_id></resource_id>
    <properties>
        <name></name>
        <value></value>
    </properties>
</create_resource_inventory>
```

I want the properties tag to repeated multiple times.

I have tried the below format for sending the parameters

```php
$body = array( 
    "user" => array (
       "now" => $now,
       "login" => $login, 
       "company" => $company,
       "auth_string" => $auth_string
    ),
    "resource_id" => $params[$i][0],
    // "new_array" => array(
    "properties" => array(
        "name" => "invtype",
        "value" => $params[$i][1]
    ),
    "properties" => array(
        "name" => "item_number",
        "value" => $params[$i][2]
    ),
    "properties" => array(
        "name" => "quantity",
        // "value" => "10"
        "value" => $params[$i][3]
    ),
    "properties" => array(
        "name" => "billable",
        "value" => $params[$i][4]
    )
```

But only one value of properties is inserted not the others

When I send request with properties value multiple times using `SOAP UI` the values are inserted in one request but doesn't work while doing it using php script.

Have looked at various questions on stack overflow but nobody answers this kind of scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the `properties` key:

```
$a = [
    'properties' => [
      'name' => 'invtype',
      'value' => 'foo'
    ],
    'properties' => [
      'name' => 'item_number',
      'value' => 'foo'
    ],
];
```

This will leave the last entry only.

Make the value of the `properties` key an array:

```
$a = [
    'properties' => [
        [
          'name' => 'invtype',
          'value' => 'foo'
        ],
        [
          'name' => 'item_number',
          'value' => 'foo'
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: The code is working now. Thanks a ton for your help !!